# Fullcalendar manually adding new events

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm adding events manually which lately will be edited. 
The problem I'm having is when I add an event and insert it into the `allDay` events. If I drag the event to the timeline zone three issues popup:

1. It adds a text called 'Object object'
2. If I resize the event the event disappears and lots of errors appears on console
3. The date-start is null so is date-end (by looking at html code)

You can checkout the problem at this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q4obhy2v/)**.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**.

The problem was the `timeFormat` object. It should be `timeFormat: 'H:mm'`.